Physics And Approximations
I started learning physics this year and one of the things I noticed is there are a lot of approximations in physics, especially in the derivation of an equation. When I am solving a problem and I come across $A\gg B$, I don't know how to continue. Is there a method or principle for approximation in physics?

Learn how to expand (1 + x)ⁿ to first order. You're going to spend the rest of your physics career using that :-)

I would argue that understanding how and when to approximate something in physics is one of, if not the, central skills of the discipline. Consequently I don't think there can be an answer to this question of any reasonable length

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question, and a very good one too. Learning how and when to make approximations and what approximations it is safe to make is a key skill in physics.

@BySymmetry I agree with the first part of your comment. An answer of  reasonable length can be created by referring the questioner to other resources, such as the Wikipedia articles on idealization (philosophy of science), spherical cow, heuristics and Fermi problems.

@gandalf61 I agree with your assessment of the question (clear and important). However, there isn't a single possible answer. As you mention, there are many ways to approach this topic. A great topic, but IMO the question doesn't fit PSE guidelines in its current form; a requirement is that a question needs to be "reasonably scoped".

This was definitely something I learned partially the hard way, we used Fowels and Cassiday "Analytical Mechanics" for undergraduate advanced mechanics. One problem on the bouncing of a ball of some coefficient of restitution asked to solve for the total distance traveled, and making use of the geometric series at some point to solve it wasn't something I thought of right away.

It is important to note that statements like $\varepsilon \ll 1$ are only meaningful when $\varepsilon$ is dimensionless. Statements such as $A \gg B$ really mean $B/A \ll 1$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ have the same dimensions.
The central tool in approximation is the Taylor series (and its generalizations). It is used so often that it pays to commit common series to memory. The general principle is that series are expanded in terms of a dimensionless quantity, even if it may not be apparent at first glance. For example, when writing $(A+B)^n = A^n + nA^{n-1}B + \ldots$, we are really expanding in powers of $B/A$, a dimensionless quantity.

Approximations are used all over the place in physics. The usual reasons are 1) they furnish useful answers with a lot less work than the exact mathematical solution, and 2) sometimes there exists no closed-form, exact solution to the equation of interest, and so approximate answers are all we have. Here are some rules of thumb of how to use them.
If you have a number which is in the denominator of a fraction and that number is way bigger than the numerator, its value is approximately zero and anything multiplied by that ratio can be approximated as zero too.
If the numerator and denominator of a fraction are nearly equal, their ratio is approximately one and any number they multiply can be approximated simply by that number.
Finally, for purposes of approximation Nielsen's Law can be conveniently invoked. It states that 0 = 1 for small values of 0 and 1.
